# What's wrong with my SQL statement, something isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, session

I have this very simple method called to check if a user has a correct password. Any help on why it isn't working? This is for Microsoft SQL Server.

```
public bool UserNameExists()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING AQUI!"))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Policia WHERE NumeroPlaca = '{0}' AND Password = '{1}'", Session.Contents["username"], Session.Contents["password"]), con))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.FieldCount > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define "isn't working". Does it crash? Exception? (if so, please post the details), produce no data? Give incorrect results? (If so, please post what you get and what you expected.)

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error when you remove the empty catch block? Are username and passwords guaranteed to only contain "safe" characters?

Comment: There's plenty wrong with your code here. First, you should be using parameters, not SQL injection, otherwise little Bobby Tables (http://xkcd.com/327/) will kill your database outright. Second, you should never swallow exceptions like that, only handle specific exceptions. Thirdly, if you only want to know if there is a matching row, you should not use `SELECT *`, you're going to retrieve much more data than you need. Even a simple `SELECT 1 AS x` should be enough.

Comment: It's not working because it's looking at the number of columns, not rows.

Comment: Fourth, **ALWAYS** hash your passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FieldCount gets the number of columns in the current row, which will always be non-zero.  You're looking for the number of rows in the result set.  Use the HasRows property.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Policia..."
```

And then:

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
if (result > 0)
{
  return true;
} 
else 
{
  return false;
}
```

Full code:

```
public bool UserNameExists()
{
  int result = int.MinValue;

  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
  {
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Policia WHERE NumeroPlaca = @username AND Password = @password";
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session.Contents["username"];
    command.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session.Contents["password"];
    result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
  }

  if (result > 0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```